# Regular Expression search for sublime3

Tags: regex, expression

I have a question, is it possible to use regex search in a sublime3 to do that thing? I search for these two < p >< /p > and then combine them in to 1.

Eg:

```
< p >lorem ipsum etc< /p > < p >lorem ipsum...< /p >
```

to

```
 < p >lorem ipsum etc lorem ipsum...< /p >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this `<\s*\/p\s*>\s*<\s*p\s*>` to replace `< /p > < p >` with a white space.

This should effectively replace this: `< /p > < p >` with this: . An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/kD9oJ1/1).

Comment: @VladGray: Glad it worked out. As a side note, please use this only for text editing purposes. Regular expressions, as a rule of thumb, should not be used to process HTML content.